# Get Folder size of HDFS from java

Tags: hdfs

I have to HDFS folder size which is having sub directories from java.

From command line we can use -dus option, But anyone can help me on how to get the same using java.

Answer (score 29):

The `getSpaceConsumed()` function in the `ContentSummary` class will return the actual space the file/directory occupies in the cluster i.e. it takes into account the replication factor set for the cluster.

For instance, if the replication factor in the hadoop cluster is set to 3 and the directory size is 1.5GB, the `getSpaceConsumed()` function will return the value as 4.5GB.

Using [`getLength()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary.html#getLength%28%29) function in the `ContentSummary` class will return you the actual file/directory size.

Answer (score 15):

You could use `getContentSummary(Path f)` method provided by the class `FileSystem`. It returns a `ContentSummary` object on which the `getSpaceConsumed()` method can be called which will give you the size of directory in bytes.

Usage :

```
package org.myorg.hdfsdemo;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class GetDirSize {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addResource(new Path(
                "/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));
        config.addResource(new Path(
                "/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
        Path filenamePath = new Path("/inputdir");
        System.out.println("SIZE OF THE HDFS DIRECTORY : " + fs.getContentSummary(filenamePath).getSpaceConsumed());
    }

}
```

HTH

Answer (score 7):

Thank you guys.

**Scala version**

```
package com.beloblotskiy.hdfsstats.model.hdfs

import java.nio.file.{Files => NioFiles, Paths => NioPaths}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.file.{Files => NioFiles}
import java.nio.file.{Paths => NioPaths}
import com.beloblotskiy.hdfsstats.common.Settings

/**
 * HDFS utilities
 * @author v-abelablotski
 */
object HdfsOps {
  private val conf = new Configuration()
  conf.addResource(new Path(Settings.pathToCoreSiteXml))
  conf.addResource(new Path(Settings.pathToHdfsSiteXml))
  private val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

  /**
   * Calculates disk usage with replication factor.
   * If function returns 3G for folder with replication factor = 3, it means HDFS has 1G total files size multiplied by 3 copies space usage.
   */
  def duWithReplication(path: String): Long = {
    val fsPath = new Path(path);
    fs.getContentSummary(fsPath).getSpaceConsumed()
  }

  /**
   * Calculates disk usage without pay attention to replication factor.
   * Result will be the same with hadopp fs -du /hdfs/path/to/directory 
   */
  def du(path: String): Long = {
    val fsPath = new Path(path);
    fs.getContentSummary(fsPath).getLength()
  }

  //...
}
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer as it is the correct explaination of the api's

Comment: I agree, also for me it was useful and correctly explained.

Answer (score 0):

### Spark-shell tool to show all tables and their consumption

A typical and illustrative tool for Spark-shell, looping loop over all bases, tables and partitions, to get sizes and report into a CSV file:

```scala
//  sshell -i script.scala > ls.csv
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

def cutPath (thePath: String, toCut: Boolean = true) : String =
  if (toCut) thePath.replaceAll("^.+/", "") else thePath

val warehouse = "/apps/hive/warehouse"  // the Hive default location for all databases
val fs = FileSystem.get( sc.hadoopConfiguration )

println(s"base,table,partitions,bytes")
fs.listStatus( new Path(warehouse) ).foreach( x => {
        val b = x.getPath.toString
        fs.listStatus( new Path(b) ).foreach( x => {
                val t = x.getPath.toString
                var parts = 0; var size = 0L; // var size3 = 0L
                fs.listStatus( new Path(t) ).foreach( x => {
                        // partition path is x.getPath.toString
                        val p_cont = fs.getContentSummary(x.getPath)
                        parts = parts + 1
                        size  = size  + p_cont.getLength
                        //size3 = size3 + p_cont.getSpaceConsumed
                }) // t loop
                println(s"${cutPath(b)},${cutPath(t)},${parts},${size}")
                // display opt  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size)
        }) // b loop
}) // warehouse loop
System.exit(0)  // get out from spark-shell
```

PS: I checked, size3 is **always** 3*size, no extra information.