# ContentSummary.getSpaceConsumed does not consider replication

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to get the disk space consumed by an HDFS directory using the `ContentSummary.getSpaceConsumed` method as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19553790/1346528).

I can't get the space consumption correctly considering the replication factor. The replication factor is 2, and I was expecting twice the size of the actual file size from the above method.

The size of the `size-test` file is 3145728 bytes. It is shown in the `dfs -ls` command along with the replication factor.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/ht$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -ls /var/lib/ubuntu
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   2 ubuntu ubuntu    3145728 2020-09-08 09:55 /var/lib/ubuntu/size-test
drwxrwxr-x   - ubuntu ubuntu          0 2020-09-07 06:37 /var/lib/ubuntu/test
```

But when I run the following code,

```
String path = "/etc/hadoop/conf/";
conf.addResource(new Path(path + "core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(path + "hdfs-site.xml"));
long size = FileContext.getFileContext(conf).util().getContentSummary(fileStatus).getSpaceConsumed();
System.out.println("Replication : " + fileStatus.getReplication());
System.out.println("File size : " + size);
```

The output is

```
Replication : 0
File size : 3145728
```

Both the file size and the replication factor seems to be incorrect.

`/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml` contains the following config:

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
```

Am I missing something here so that the replication factor is ignored by the DFS APIs?